# MySQL, move data from rows to columns

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, pivot-table

I have a MySQL table that has the following data:

```
id    userid    fieldid    data
--    ------    -------    ----
 1    186       1          London
 2    186       3          Accountant
 3    186       5          Joe Jones
 4    206       1          Paris
 5    206       5          Mark Smith
 6    210       1          Berlin
 7    210       2          0020
 8    210       3          Farmer
 9    210       4          000-000-0000
10    210       5          Bill Johnson
```

etc.

What I want to end up with is another table with the data formatted into rows based on the userid:

```
userid   Region    Acct    Title         Phone           Name
------   ------    ----    -----         -----           ----
  186    London    NULL    Accountant    NULL            Joe Jones
  206    Paris     NULL    NULL          NULL            Mark Smith
  210    Berlin    0020    Farmer        000-000-0000    Bill Johnson
```

I don't need a SELECT statement... I know how to see the data with a GROUP_CONCAT. I'm talking about another table (maybe a virtual table?) with the data in rows.

I wouldn't mind a script that references row names and column names but I didn't want to refer to the specific data fields (i.e. - if row_data = London move to column1).

I'd rather say something like "IF fieldid = 1 then move 'data' to new_table.column1" but I haven't the slightest idea how to say this.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Well if you know how to do it with select statement then use that same select and push data to temp table or physical table (whichever you need). No?

Comment: Do you have a table that references each `FieldId` so you know what the name is supposed to be?  Do you really want to store this data in a table?  You have the ability to transform it as needed.

Comment: The problem is that I was trying to use "WHERE region = London" in a script, but that was filtering out all the other rows (like Name and Phone Number). I don't know how to do this any other way except create a table where everything is in a separate column rather than stacked in 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `temptable` AS 
SELECT userid, MAX(IF(fieldid =1, DATA, NULL)) Region, 
       MAX(IF(fieldid=2, DATA, NULL)) Acct, MAX(IF(fieldid =3, DATA, NULL)) Title, 
       MAX(IF(fieldid=4, DATA, NULL)) Phone, MAX(IF(fieldid =5, DATA, NULL)) `Name` 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
create table mynewtable as
(the select statement you already know )
```

Comment: This statement crams every item into one column. I want each row item to be in a separate column.

Comment: well - i thought you said you already knew the sql to do that part - sorry